# High iowait on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: server, iowait

I have a server with Ubuntu 20.04 that ran without problems for a while. However, since a week ago, problems started to arise as everything became slow. On the server I run Virtualizor with a number of VM (VPS) servers.

It looks like everything is so slow because of high iowait. The server runs 3x a Samsung 870 QVO 1TB SSD. Can someone explain why there is such high iowait and how to solve it?

Command: `iotop -aoP`

```
454444 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 % 15.71 % [kworker/u130:3-events_unbound]
 453682 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  4.63 % [kworker/u130:1+flush-8:0]
   1053 be/3 root          0.00 B     96.00 K  0.00 %  4.44 % [jbd2/sda5-8]
   5710 be/4 libvirt-      6.27 M      9.02 M  0.00 %  1.29 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1019,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
   3525 be/4 libvirt-   1276.00 K     15.32 M  0.00 %  1.21 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1017,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
   5766 be/4 libvirt-      2.18 M      3.39 M  0.00 %  0.79 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1018,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
  11654 be/4 libvirt-     44.00 K   1200.00 K  0.00 %  0.72 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1012,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
   5811 be/4 libvirt-      0.00 B    976.00 K  0.00 %  0.61 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1004,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
 454732 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.11 % [kworker/1:0-events]
   5869 be/4 libvirt-      0.00 B     28.00 K  0.00 %  0.11 % qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=v1201,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libv~=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
 274709 be/7 netdata    1188.00 K      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.06 % netdata -D -P /var/run/netdata/netdata.pid
    669 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.01 % [xfsaild/sda3]
    752 be/3 root          0.00 B      3.66 M  0.00 %  0.00 % systemd-journald
   1244 be/4 root          0.00 B     12.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start
   1693 be/4 emps          0.00 B     16.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
 328592 be/4 syslog        0.00 B    164.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -n -iNONE
```